# Get a certain value of data store in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4

I'm new to ExtJS. I have a combobox in ExtJS and I want to load the first record of the store to be the default value of the combobox. here's my code

```
var cutoff = store_dynamic('nr/getCutOffDate', true);
var combo_value = //here i want to store the default value taken in the store

xtype: 'combobox',
margin: '0 10 0 0',
labelWidth: 80,
width: 240,
store: cutoff,
displayField: 'date',
valueField: 'dt_val',
fieldLabel: 'Cut-Off Date',
editable: false,
id: 'cutoffdate',
value: combo_value
```

Here's the data in the store

```
{"success":true,"metaData":{"fields":["date","dt_val"]},"data [{"date":"June 30, 2015","dt_val":"6\
/30\/2015"},{"date":"June 15, 2015","dt_val":"6\/15\/2015"}]}
```

The `dt_val` are what displayed in the combobox.

Answer (score 1):

This would be really easy, the general case being

```
var store = combo.getStore(),
    value = store.getAt(0).get(combo.valueField);
combo.setValue(value);
```

or, in your special case:

```
combo_value = cutoff.getAt(0).get('dt_val');
```

But I guess that your code the problem could occur that the store is not yet filled with data when you initialize the combobox. You would be better off to do it in the combo's `afterrender` and the store's `load` event, and check whether `combo.rendered` and `store.getCount()>0` are both `true` before you set the combo's value.